# GMap, gmap3 plugin and 'getRoute' call that changed object received in result

Tags: google-maps, jquery-gmap3, map-directions

I'm still not sure I'm seeing it right, but here it is:

I'm using jquery gmap3 plugin for getting some routing from Google Maps. Plugin is v4.1.
Normally, in callback function for `getRoute` action, I was getting a response (let's have it in var named `results`), which had structure like this:

```
results.routes - an array of google.maps.DirectionsRoutes
results.status - status of the call ('OK' in normal situations)
results.ub (this one I used to pull the waypoints from)
```

The `results.ub` object doesn't exist any more. Now there is a `results.vb`.

I thought that may be a change that's coming form the gmap3 plugin itself, but i have the plugin files on my HDD and they were not changed for months. Anyone has an explanation?

I can just simply change my code and start using the object named "vb", which IS there right now, but what if it changes to "wb" in 2 days?

Comment: So far it seems like "ub" object is an undocumented feature which possibly changes from time to time. Official GMap API says it will only return the array of DirectionsRoutes objects and nothing else, while it actually does do return more.

Comment: I just wanted to share how this ended - my previous comment was right. GMap did simply started using different naming. Now it returns the "vb" object, which holds the list of waypoints object.

Answer (score 0):

If the object result change, this is done by google itself,

gmap3 doesn't modify the result object

*an notice version 5.0 of gmap3 has just been released*